# Visual Studio не могу разобраться с файлами проекта - C++ IDE

Tags: c#, c++, c, visual-studio

Работаю со сборкой Sqlite для Net и столкнулся с такой проблемой
 
1.Исключаю файл из проекта
 
2.Потом обратно добавляю
 
3.Уже компилируется с ошибкой
 
Файлы такие в проекте помечены кружок со знаком минус,
  а когда обратно добавляешь он уже без минуса
 
Что этот круг обозначает?
 
Что я делаю не правильно?
 
[image: Фото прилагается]

Comment: Может ссылку на сборку обновить надо?

Comment: Это как? Все стандартные методы сборки очистки и просто перезапуска я уже делал.Все равно куча ошибок и это ошибки линкера(компоновщика)

Answer (score 1):

Извиняюсь все понял это просто означает, что файл исключен из проекта, а в проводнике обозревателя проектов отображается.
Настраивается правой кнопкой -> Свойства -> Общие -> Исключен из сборки -> Да\Нет